# SSRS optional cascading parameter for date

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that I am attempting to setup a subscription for. The subscriber would like the report on the 4th every month for the previous month's end date. e.g ran today would return the data through 10/31.

I would like to create this report so that there is a cascading parameter that would be labeled Use previous month end date to set the end date to the subscription date when flagged on and allow the user to enter a date when flagged off. so that i can use this parameter to create the dynamic subscription but allow anyone else hitting it through the report server to enter their own date.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `UsePriorMonth` parameter - just default the date range to be the prior month and allow users to change it if they want.

So your `DateFrom` parameter `Default Value` expression is:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-Day(Today), Today))
```

and your `DateTo` parameter `Default Value` expression is:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-Day(Today), Today))
```

Comment: The simplest answer is always the easier thank you for this I was thinking way to hard about this.